# Call-time pass-by-reference

Tags: php, html, algorithm, fatal-error, boyer-moore

There is Fatal Error in this code:

> Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed on line 108. this is
>   Boyer Moore Algorithm

```
function suffixes($pattern, &$suffixes)
{
   $m = strlen($pattern);

   $suffixes[$m - 1] = $m;
   $g = $m - 1;

   for ($i = $m - 2; $i >= 0; --$i) {
      if ($i > $g && $suffixes[$i + $m - 1 - $f] < $i - $g) {
         $suffixes[$i] = $suffixes[$i + $m - 1 - $f];
      } else {
         if ($i < $g) {
            $g = $i;
         }
         $f = $i;

         while ($g >= 0 && $pattern[$g] == $pattern[$g + $m - 1 - $f]) {
            $g--;
         }
         $suffixes[$i] = $f - $g;
      }
   }
}
```

**function badCharacters**

```
 function badCharacters($pattern, &$badChars)
    {
       $m = strlen($pattern);

       for ($i = 0; $i < $m - 1; ++$i) {
          $badChars[$pattern{$i}] = $m - $i - 1;
       }
    }
```

**function goodSuffixes**

```
function goodSuffixes($pattern, &$goodSuffixes)
{
   $m       = strlen($pattern);
   $suff    = array();

   suffixes($pattern, $suff);

   for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++) {
      $goodSuffixes[$i] = $m;
   }

   for ($i = $m - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
      if ($suff[$i] == $i + 1) {
         for ($j = 0; $j < $m - $i - 1; $j++) {
            if ($goodSuffixes[$j] == $m) {
               $goodSuffixes[$j] = $m - $i - 1;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   for ($i = 0; $i < $m - 2; $i++) {
      $goodSuffixes[$m - 1 - $suff[$i]] = $m - $i - 1;
   }
}
```

**function boyer_moore**

```
function boyer_moore($pattern, $text)
{
   $n = strlen($text);
   $m = strlen($pattern);

   $goodSuffixes    = array();
   $badCharacters   = array();

 //this is the line 108
   goodSuffixes($pattern, &$goodSuffixes);
   badCharacters($pattern, &$badCharacters);

   $j = 0;
   while ($j < $n - $m) {
      for ($i = $m - 1; $i >= 0 && $pattern[$i] == $text[$i + $j]; $i--);
      if ($i < 0) {
         echo $j;
         $j += $goodSuffixes[0];
      } else {
         $j += max($goodSuffixes[$i], $badCharacters[$text[$i + $j]] - $m + $i + 1);
      }
   }
}

boyer_moore($pattern, $text);
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific *problem* or *error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It's clear from the error message:

```
goodSuffixes($pattern, &$goodSuffixes);
badCharacters($pattern, &$badCharacters);
```

The '&' is the character that is attempting to pass by reference at calltime.  Remove the '&' from in front of the 2 variable names.

```
goodSuffixes($pattern, $goodSuffixes);
badCharacters($pattern, $badCharacters);
```